# Python raspberry pi GPIO Logic error

Tags: python, gpio

Hi guys could anybody spot my mistake all i wanted to do is when GPIO.input(22) is called it will wait for gpio.input(11) before calling a method i have tried to compare the time but it seems that it cannot leave the loop. Thanks

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
import threading
import MySQLdb

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(15, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)

db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","root","test" )
cursor = db.cursor()

class Variable:
    count = 0
    people = 0
    times = 0
    decision = 0
    choice = 0

def countdown():
    GPIO.output(15, False)
    time.sleep(5)
    GPIO.output(15, True)

t = threading.Timer(5.0, countdown)   
def enterexit():
    global t  # You need this to tell Python that you're going to change the global t variable. If you don't do this, using 't = ..' will just create a local t variable.
    if int(Variable.choice == 1):
        print("Entered")
        print ("TIME: " + datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
        sql = """INSERT INTO `timing`( `Time`, `Date`) VALUES (CURTIME(), CURDATE())"""
        t.start()
    else:
        if(Variable.decision == 1):            
            print("Entered")
            print ("TIME: " + datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
            sql = """INSERT INTO `timing`( `Time`, `Date`) VALUES (CURTIME(), CURDATE())"""
            t.cancel()
            t.join()         # here you block the main thread until the timer is completely stopped
            t = threading.Timer(5.0, countdown)
            t.start()
        elif(Variable.decision == 2):            
            print("Exit")
            print ("TIME: " + datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
            sql = """INSERT INTO `timing`( `Time`, `Date`) VALUES (CURTIME(), CURDATE())"""
            t.cancel()
            t.join()         # here you block the main thread until the timer is completely stopped
            t = threading.Timer(5.0, countdown)
            t.start()


while True:
    global sensor1
    global sensor2
    global Time1
    global Time2
    if GPIO.input(22):
        Time1 = datetime.now().strftime('%H%M%S')
        while True:
            if GPIO.input(11):
                 GPIO.output(18, False)
                 GPIO.output(18, True)
                 Time2 = datetime.now().strftime('%H%M%S')
                 if(Time1 < Time2):
                     Variable.count+=1
                     Variable.choice += 1
                     Variable.people += 1
                     Variable.decision = 1
                     enterexit()
                     break
            else:
                print("Waiting")

    elif GPIO.input(11):
        Time2 = datetime.now().strftime('%H%M%S')
        while True:
            if GPIO.input(22):
                GPIO.output(7, False)
                GPIO.output(7, True)
                Variable.count-=1
                Time1 = datetime.now().strftime('%H%M%S')
                if(Time2 < Time1):
                    Variable.people -= 1
                    print(Variable.people)
                    Variable.decision = 2
                    enterexit()
                    break
            else:
                print("Waiting")

    else:
        Variable.count = 0

db.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

A few questions:

- With `Time1 < Time` you are comparing strings. Is this the behaviour you want? Or in other words: Why are you using `strftime()`?
- Why are `Time1` and `Time2` global?